# Visual Studio 2013 - Search Short Cuts (hot keys)

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2013

In visual Studio, is there a way I can set up hot keys to quickly switch between searching in all open documents, entire solution or current document?

It is sooooo slow to have to use the mouse to change the option from the ctrl+f or chift+ctrl+f search menu.

...gregory

Answer (score 0):

Please see this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

**On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
Expand Environment, and then choose Keyboard.**

this is a command for find in files 'Edit.FindinFiles' default hot key is 'Ctrl + Shift + F'.

You add any new short key as you like

Hope this help....

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to have the option for hot keying where it looks. I want to be able to hit a hot key and search in just open files, or select a different hot key and search the entire solution without having to change (via the mouse) the "look in" value. Make sense? Am I missing something?